# File transfer between EC2 instances using scp results in "Bad owner or permissions"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

#### What I am trying to do

I have two ec2 instances—**ec2A** (Tokyo) & **ec2B** (Singapore)—they are both running on *Amazon Linux 2*. I would like to transfer a folder of images (~450MB in total) from **ec2A** to **ec2B**.

#### My issue

Running `scp -i ec2B.pem images.tar ec2-user@<ec2B Public IP>:/path/to/destination` in **ec2A**'s terminal results in *"Bad owner or permissions on /home/ec2-user/.ssh/config"*

#### What I've tried

I've tried following [this guide](https://blog.e-zest.com/how-to-do-scp-from-one-ec2-instance-to-another-ec2-instance/) but the same error still persist

Comment: Can you successfully ssh using the same configuration? eg: `ssh -i ec2B.pem ec2-user@<ec2B Public IP>`

Comment: @JohnRotenstein No, it shows the same error

Comment: try this. chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config

Comment: @saranjeetsingh ec2A's ~/.ssh/config permission is 664

Comment: change for both ec2A and B to 600 and try

Comment: @saranjeetsingh hmm... ec2B doesn't appear to have a ~/.ssh/config

Comment: ok.. have you tried ec2A with 600 then ? same error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config` in ec2A.